# Digital I/O: MSP430

Tags: msp430, ti-ccstudio

My question is: Write a program which controls 8 LEDs connected to Port 2 of the MSP430.
A momentary switch (push button) should be connected to Port 1.5
When the button is pressed, the LEDs should form an 8-bit binary counter counting from 00h to FFh
and then back to 00h.
When the button is not pressed, the LEDs should be animated so that the light sweeps from side to
side.
I have written this code so far:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; MSP430 Assembler Code Template for use with TI Code Composer Studio
;
;
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .cdecls C,LIST,"msp430.h"       ; Include device header file
            
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .def    RESET                   ; Export program entry-point to
                                            ; make it known to linker.
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .text                           ; Assemble into program memory.
            .retain                         ; Override ELF conditional linking
                                            ; and retain current section.
            .retainrefs                     ; And retain any sections that have
                                            ; references to current section.

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESET       mov.w   #__STACK_END,SP         ; Initialize stackpointer
StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW|WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer
ENIO        clr     PM5CTL0

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Main loop here
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            mov.b   #00h, P1SEL0    ;Set port 1 to I/O
            mov.b   #00h, P1SEL1

            mov.b   #0FFh - 1<<5, P1DIR
            mov.b   #1<<5, P1REN

            clr.b   P1OUT

            mov.b   #00h, P2SEL0    ;Set port 2 to I/O
            mov.b   #00h, P2SEL1

            mov.b   #0FFh, P2DIR    ;Sets P2 as outputs

            clr.b   P2OUT           ;Clears

ifbtn:      cmp.b   #0, P1IN
            jeq     shiftleft
            mov.b   R12, P2OUT
            inc.b   R12
            mov.b   #0, R11
            mov.b   #01h, R10
            jmp     ifbtn

shiftleft:  mov     #0, R12         ;Shift left
            mov.b   R10, P2OUT
            cmp.b   #0, R11
            jne     shiftright
            rla     R10
            cmp     #80h, R10
            jne     end

shiftright: mov     #1, R11         ;Shift right
            rra     R10
            cmp     #1, R10
            jne     end
            mov     #0, R11

end:        nop
            nop
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Stack Pointer definition
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .global __STACK_END
            .sect   .stack
            
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Interrupt Vectors
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .sect   ".reset"                ; MSP430 RESET Vector
            .short  RESET
```

The code looks like this because it is an empty assembly-only project where you only write to the "main loop here" section. I have connected the leds to my breadboard then to my MSP-EXP430FR6989, however I cannot seem to get the correct things to happen.

Comment: Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/102984).

Comment: I think you can get more effective answers in the forum specific for this great 16 bit MCU holded by TI: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum

Comment: you say `My question is:`  and then you do not ask a question ... describing a problem is not asking a question

Comment: Logan, The very first thing to do is to decide which peripherals you want to include in your design, if any. For example, you could decide to use a timer to help you. Or, you might decide, `no, I'll just use busy loops`. Regardless, you have choices to make and a design to propose that would convince others that you are on the right track. How do you propose to achieve the given goals? (And I don't mean one or two of them. I mean ***all*** of them.) How do you see the program design here?